# Missing characters in filled pdf using PDFTk with encoding UTF-8

Tags: php, pdf, encoding, pdftk, fdf

I'm trying to fill pdf documents using PDFTk. Script working fine, it fills inputs in form but I don't get special characters [polish charset: UTF-8 or ISO-8859-2].

Script: https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk

The weird thing is that generated pdf actually has polish characters when I click on field.

**Before click:**

[image]

**After click on field:**

[image]

---

Default encoding is set to UTF-8. The problem is that PDFTk can't use chars outside the standard ASCII with FDF form fill. It doesn't allow multi-byte characters.

***What I did:***

1. Add fonts to pdf files (checked and files has font)
2. Create fields in pdf files with default font (Arial)
3. Change encoding in script (function fillForm) to ISO-8859-2
4. Change data values encoding (iconv or mb_convert_encoding)
5. Change functions encoding and data value encoding to ISO-8859-2
6. Flatten pdf after filling the form
7. Read all topics about this problem in stackoverflow, google

> **UPDATE (25.03.2016)**: Findout that pdf documents works fine on some computers. Some people have polish characters and other don't. All of
>   us have right fonts (with polish charset). I used default Arial or
>   Times New Roman. Fonts are also embed in that file.

Any ideas?

Comment: i have this same issue with even with Times New Roman fonts.
But its because of LibreOffice PDF export,

Comment: Its seems its not because of missing font characters.My issue begin right after exporting PDF from LibreOffice Writer

Answer (score 8):

you need to run pdftk with `need_appearances` as an [argument](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-output-need-appearances).

kudos to the guys from [this issue](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk/issues/4) on github.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helped me get my issue sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.
Solved it with `utf8_decode` function. eg `utf8_decode('Łukasz')`

Answer (score 0):

The best results (without flatten) I got when I was creating FDF file with UTF-8 values encoded into UTF-18BE

```
chr(0xfe) . chr(0xff) . str_replace(array('\\', '(', ')'), array('\\\\', '\(', '\)'), mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-16BE'));
```

Your library works quite well but ie. when I open the PDF generated with it directly in Safari on MACOS it does not show polish chars until I click the field. When I open it with Adobe Reader - it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

I could not find how to change font, so my solution - use itext, https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-5/filling-out-forms

wrote for my project https://github.com/dddeeemmmooonnn/pdf_form_filler

Comment: Please show the portion in your project where you used itext to solve similar problem.

Comment: @Nabil Farhan I didn't understand the question exactly. I need to fill out the form in Cyrillic in laravel project. pdftk did not display cyrillic until you click to field, font problem