# Filling pdf forms with non-English characters

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdftk, poppler

I am filling pdf forms and serving them to users on my express web server:

```
const pdfFillForm = require('pdf-fill-form');

let FillData = {
    text: 'Title'
}

const pdf = pdfFillForm.writeSync(Form.path, 
        FillData, { "save": "pdf" } );

res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + `filename.pdf`);
res.type("application/pdf");
res.send(pdf);
```

The above code works fine, until the contents of `FillData` contains Asian characters.
Any non-English character renders blank. I have also tried a very similar setup using another similar library `fill-pdf`, which uses a different library under the hood. But this lib has a similar problem, characters are encoded incorrectly, something like:

`ã…Žã…«ã‡¼ã…«ã‡°ç”‰åł½ç¬¬ä¸•ç”‰å¥³ ã‡¢ã‡¤ã…ªã‡¹`

How can I correctly encode my pdfs to display both languages? Any alternatives? I understand this issue likely stems from `pdftk` and `Poppler`. Both of these node libs allow you to pass configuration args, but I have been unable to find any documentation regarding encoding in these libs.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44445460/2463368) mentions having to use the need_appearances flag with pdftk when filling a form with non-ASCII characters.

Comment: unfortunately does not seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a seven years old Poppler bug without a solution: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/362

Comment: Yikes. Well maybe one day.

Comment: I tried to make the day closer: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/j2sg51/