# What is the perfect way to fill acroforms using CLI Linux tool or NodeJS module?

Tags: node.js, linux, pdf-form

I have a task where I need to fill in PDF Forms. I think they are called Acroforms but I am not sure. It is opposit to XFA Forms (embedded in PDFs), Acroforms are less dynamic, they don't have many features compared to XFA.

I am coding for NodeJS, so I tried its module `pdffiller`. This library is only a wrapper for so-called `pdftk` or `PDF Toolkit`.
It took me almost one day to figure out how to use it on my Ubuntu 18.04 development laptop. I couldn't install it or compile, so I had to download [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mnuessler/pdftk/), unpack it and place compiled `pdftk` in specific system folders to allow `pdffiller` to work (lib goes here `/usr/lib/x86_64-Linux-gnu/libgcj.so.16.0.0`, binary goes here `/usr/local/bin/pdftk`).

Then there go the forms. Those downloaded from official government webpage (these are tax return forms) are XFA forms, these do not work with `pdftk` - all I get is a request for password which I don't have.

```
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   tax-return-form.pdf
   OWNER PASSWORD REQUIRED, but not given (or incorrect)
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

We took the other approach, we bought Adobe Acrobat DC to convert flat PDFs to simple Acroforms. Then we tested again what `PDF Toolkit` can do. Two problems are blockers, and dim `pdftk` unusable for us:

1. No output for Polish diactrict signs (ąęćśżźnó)
2. <strike>No ability to check a checkbox</strike>

And the tax form has plenty of those checkboxes!

I would like to as what tool should we use? Is there any opensource or free for commercial use that will fill PDF Forms properly?

Edit:
I found the way to select  checkboxes. After using `pdftk dump_data_fields_utf8` method I got a file with a lot of information about  fields:

```
---
FieldType: Button
FieldName: checkbox3
FieldFlags: 0
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: Off
FieldStateOption: Yes
---
```

The checkbox above has FieldStateOption: Off or Yes. Just putting `Yes` in JSON field-value map mad checkboxes selected.

Comment: Here is a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196850/missing-characters-in-filled-pdf-using-pdftk-with-encoding-utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doable, but:

1. there is no utf-8 fonts if one uses 'flatten' option
2. has to use 'need_appearances' which excludes 'flatten'
3. Ubuntu's PDF Viewer Evince 3.28.4 doesn't know how to display polish fonts
4. Firefox, Chrome, Adobe Reader 9 for Linux does display UTF fonts properly.
5. and fanks for the downvote without explanation why, SO sucks as usual.