# Pdftk cyrillic characters encoding

Tags: php, pdftk

When i flatten a pdf document using pdftk the cyrillic characters don't appear correctly.
`а о й` gets converted to `Ð° Ð¾ Ð`

I tried changing the encoding on the pdf , passing the data through `utf8_decode()` - that only worked for letters such as `ä ø`, converting the encoding with `mb_convert_encoding()` and so on.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: PDFTK does not have full UTF-8 support, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973283/flatten-fdf-xfdf-forms-to-pdf-in-php-with-utf-8-characters)

Comment: Encode with UTF-16.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047970/weird-characters-when-filling-pdf-with-pdftk/19170162#19170162